# Copy and Pasting a Dynamic Range based on data entry

Tags: vba, excel

Hi I need some help with vba coding.

I have worksheets within a workbook that all look the same with date as the column heading.

Is there a way to have a data entry screen pop-up and the user to enter the date for the first column to start copying from and then ask another question for the end date of the last column to copy.

I want excel to find these two dates from the data entry screen within a specific sheet, copy the information, and then paste this information into same column headings starting on row 4 to row 34.

(rows will stay constant for copy and pasting, columns will change based on the user input)

I can record a macro to copy and paste, but i'm not sure how to make it dynamic.

Hopefully someone out there may have an idea.

Comment: Try first (recording could be a start) and then come back with a more specific question concerning your coding trial and errors.

Answer (score 0):

You could create inputbox to prompt user to enter a date and then pass the value into a defined variable.

```
Dim start_date As Date
start_date = InputBox("Please enter the start date:")
```

User entered date now is stored in variable called `start_date`. Then you could use function `Find` to search the location of this date in your worksheet. e.g.

```
Dim x As Range
With ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.UsedRange
    Set x = .Find(start_date, LookIn:=xlValues)
End With
```

you can replace `UsedRange` with the specific area in the worksheet you want it to be searched against. Now, x is the range(or cell) that contains the date user entered.

Just apply the same concept to find the end date, and then integrate these info into the copy-paste routine.

Hope this will help!